# bash: How to add space in string?

Tags: string, bash, spaces

I have a string like this:

```
string="aaa-bbb"
```

But I want to add space before char '-', so I want this:

```
aaa -bbb
```

I tried a lot of things, but I can't add space there. I tried with `echo $string | tr '-' ' -'`, and some other stuff, but it didn't work...

I have Linux Mint: GNU bash, version 4.3.8(1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No need to call `sed`, use [string substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace) native in BASH:

```
$ foo="abc-def-ghi"
$ echo "${foo//-/ -}"
abc -def -ghi
```

Note the *two slashes* after the variable name: the first slash replaces the first occurrence, where two slashes replace every occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

Bash has builtin string substitution.

```
$ string="aaa-bbb"
$ result="${string/-/ -}"
$ echo "$result"
aaa -bbb
```

Alternatively, you can use `sed` or `perl`:

```
$ string="aaa-bbb"
$ result=$(sed 's/-/ -/' <<< $string)
$ echo "$result"
aaa -bbb
$ result=$(perl -pe 's/-/ -/' <<< $string)
$ echo "$result"
aaa -bbb
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this:

```
printf "%s\n" "${string}" | sed 's/-/ -/g'
```

It looks for `-` and replace it with `-` (space hyphen)

Answer (score 1):

`tr` can only substitute one character at a time. what you're looking for is `sed`:

`echo "$string" | sed 's/-/ -/'`

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the shell to echo an un-quoted variable `$string`.
When that happens, spaces inside variables are used to split the string:

```
$ string="a -b -c"
$ printf '<%s>\n' $string
<a>
<-b>
<-c>
```

The variable does contain the spaces, just that you are not seeing it correctly.
[Quote your expansions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/79743)

```
$ printf '<%s>\n' "$string"
<a -b -c>
```

---

To get your variable changed from `-` to `-` there are many solutions:

sed: `string="$(echo "$string" | sed 's/-/ -/g')"; echo "$string"`
bash: `string="${string//-/ -}; echo "$string"`